# Spark failed to submit jobs to remote yarn cluster with java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to Spark and Hadoop. I configured a single-node Hadoop cluster on a Windows machine and was trying to submit jobs to it on a Mac laptop.

The command I used is

```
    ./pyspark --master yarn --deploy-mode client
```

and my `yarn.site.xml` file is as follows:

```
 <configuration>
   <property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
   <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
 </property>

 <property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
 </property>

  <property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
  <value>192.168.0.11:8032</value>
  </property>

<property>
 <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
 <value>192.168.0.11:8025</value>
</property>

 <property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
  <value>192.168.0.11:8030</value>
 </property>


   <property>
   <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
   <value>false</value>
   </property>


   </configuration>
```

This file is same on the cluster as on the laptop. The error messages in the yarn logs looks like following

`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "49187'"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:272)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.parseHostPort(Utils.scala:980)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.waitForSparkDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:555)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runExecutorLauncher(ApplicationMaster.scala:433)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:764)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$2.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:762)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:785)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
18/01/23 21:24:51 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 10, (reason: Uncaught exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "49187'")`

I read bunch of the yarn resourcemanager's stderr message and found out

`INFO amlauncher.AMLauncher: Command to launch container container_1516760256160_0002_02_000001 : {{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java,-server,-Xmx512m,-Djava.io.tmpdir={{PWD}}/tmp,-Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=<LOG_DIR>,org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher,--arg,'192.168.0.12:49187',--properties-file,{{PWD}}/__spark_conf__/__spark_conf__.properties,1>,<LOG_DIR>/stdout,2>,<LOG_DIR>/stderr`

where the number `49187` shows up. However, I don't know where the above command is called. Can someone point out how I can fix this issue?

Comment: are you putting single quotes around `--arg` arguments? or is something else doing it?

Comment: No, I never call the above command, I think it's automatically generated. @cowbert

Comment: Could you please add --master local[*] and let me know.

Comment: `at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.parseHostPort`... Something in your configurations are off

Comment: `pyspark --master local[*]` works fine @Souvik

Comment: I guess something wrong with the port, do you know how to fix it? @cricket_007

Comment: I'm honestly not sure where the 49187 port reference comes from

Comment: Me either, I didn't set the port anywhere ... @cricket_007